# Как сделать, чтобы при разных разрешениях телефона программа выглядела одинаково libGDX

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр, libgdx, экран

Проблема в том, что никак не могу этого добиться. Вот что у меня уже есть:
package game.ani.elementx;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public class CardGame extends ApplicationAdapter{
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Sprite backgrSprite;
    Texture card;
    Texture backgrText;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    final float GAME_WORLD_WIDTH = 1920;
    final float GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT = 1080;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        card = new Texture("cardback.png");
        backgrText = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("battlefield1.png"));
        backgrSprite = new Sprite(backgrText);
        backgrSprite.setPosition(0,0);
        float aspectRation = (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT/aspectRation, GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(GAME_WORLD_WIDTH/2, GAME_WORLD_HEIGHT/2,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        //batch.draw(backgrSprite, 0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        backgrSprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        card.dispose();
    }
}
```

Поле у меня должно быть 1920х1080, а если у телефона разрешение экрана меньше - оно должно сжиматься, больше - растягиватся. Как-то так.

Comment: Не знаю поможет ли вам мой комментарий, но я видел как в обычном приложении андроид умножают пиксели на коэффициент dp. Подробнее: https://coderoad.ru/4605527/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-dp